# Uncaught You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have form:

```
new Ext.form.FormPanel({ 
    bodyStyle:'padding: 10px',
    width:400,
    renderTo: Ext.query(".foo")[0], 
    id: 'login-form',   
    bodyStyle: 'padding:15px;',
    url:'1.php',
    items: [            
            {   xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Login',
                name: 'login'           

            },
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'pass',           
                fieldLabel: 'Password',
                inputType: 'password'  

            }],
      buttons: [{                         
                text: 'Login',
                handler: function()
                  { Ext.getCmp('login-form')   
                        .getForm()              
                        .submit();
                }}]
    });
```

Error:
**Uncaught You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String:** 

**Notice: Undefined index: pass in C:\xampp\htdocs\extjs\1.php on line**

Why Undefined?

```
 {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'pass',           // имя поля <input name=«pass»
                    fieldLabel: 'Password',
                    inputType: 'password'   // Не просто  textfield, а  password

                }
```

name:'pass'!

My php file:

```
$pass = $_GET["pass"];
$json = '{"a":pass}';
echo json_decode($json);
```

Comment: It would be largely helpful if you commented your code in English...

Comment: Come on, his comments wouldn't be of any use regarding his question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says it all, undefined index in your PHP. Ext forms are send using a POST request by default, so your code should be:

```
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
```

If you don't know what the HTTP method is used (boo, that's bad!), you can even use `$_REQUEST` instead.

Moreover, as stated in the other answer, the rest of your PHP is scrambled... What you really want to do is that (look, I using the force!):

```
echo json_encode(array('a' => $pass));
```

And to finally answer your original question, your javascript error message is the one you get when Ext fails to decode a JSON response. That's good to know for identifying quickly where a problem comes from.

Comment: ... This isn't always the case? You can decide yourself whether a form is sent via post or get

Comment: @JeffShaver You're right, forgot the "by default" part. Fixed now, thanks.

Comment: Thanks!!I am glad.How to redirect to 1.php when  submit()?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is nothing to do with ExtJS and more to do with your JSON output from PHP:

```
$pass = $_GET["pass"];
$json = '{"a":pass}';
echo json_decode($json);
```

Probably should be:

```
$pass = $_GET["pass"];
$json = '{"a": "' . $pass . '"}';

echo $json;
```

I'm assuming `pass` is a string and I'm not sanitising it. Also you don't want to decode on the PHP side, you simply want to dump the JSON you've already encoded to output for ExtJS to consume.